# unicode class in Python

Tags: python, unicode

`help(unicode)` prints something like:

```
class unicode(basestring)
 |  unicode(string [, encoding[, errors]]) -> object
...
```

but you can use something different from a basestring as argument, you can do unicode(1) and get u'1'. What happens in that call? int don't have a __unicode__ method to be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `__unicode__` exists it is called, otherwise it falls back to `__str__`

```
class A(int):
    def __str__(self):
        print "A.str"
        return int.__str__(self)

    def __unicode__(self):
        print "A.unicode"
        return int.__str__(self)

class B(int):
    def __str__(self):
        print "B.str"
        return int.__str__(self)


unicode(A(1)) # prints "A.unicode"
unicode(B(1)) # prints "B.str"
```

Answer (score 2):

Same as `unicode(str(1))`.

```
>>> class thing(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         print "__str__ called on " + repr(self)
...         return repr(self)
...
>>> a = thing()
>>> a
<__main__.thing object at 0x7f2f972795d0>
>>> unicode(a)
__str__ called on <__main__.thing object at 0x7f2f972795d0>
u'<__main__.thing object at 0x7f2f972795d0>'
```

---

If you really want to see the gritty bits underneath, open up the Python interpreter source code.

`Objects/unicodeobject.c#PyUnicode_Type` defines the `unicode` type, with constructor `.tp_new=unicode_new`.

Since the optional arguments `encoding` or `errors` are not given, and a `unicode` object is being constructed (as opposed to a `unicode` subclass), `Objects/unicodeobject.c#unicode_new` calls `PyObject_Unicode`.

`Objects/object.c#PyObject_Unicode` calls the `__unicode__` method if it exists.  If not, it falls back to `PY_Type(v)->tp_str` (a.k.a. `__str__`) or `PY_Type(v)->tp_repr` (a.k.a. `__repr__`).  It then passes the result to `PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject`.

`Objects/unicodeobject.c#PyUnicode_FromEncodedObject` finds that it was given a string, and passes it on to `PyUnicode_Decode`, which returns a `unicode` object.

Finally, `PyObject_Unicode` returns to `unicode_new`, which returns this `unicode` object.

In short, `unicode()` will automatically stringify your object if it needs to.  This is Python working as expected.

Comment: I mean... what happens internally.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no `__unicode__` method, the `__str__` method will be called instead. Regardless of which of these methods is called, if a `unicode` is returned, it will be passed on as-is. If a `str` is returned, it will be decoded using the default encoding, as returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding()`, which should almost always be `'ascii'`. If some other kind of object is returned, a `TypeError` will be raised.

(It is possible, by reloading the sys module, to change the default encoding by calling `sys.setdefaultencoding()`; this is basically always a bad idea.)